# Clicked list item into a String and transported to another activity

Tags: java, android

I have made this app where in one particular activity i have a all the items listed in a list view. when you click the list item it goes to another activity where similar thing is happening. after that i was the clicked list items to be converted into a strings and transported into a 3rd activity where i can display those.
when i try to display them this shows in the text view where the clicked text item should have appeared:
[image]

this is code for the first activity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Objects;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class TicketCategory extends AppCompatActivity {
public static String Category;

public String getCategory() {
    return Category;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ticket_category);

    populateTicketCategoryList();

   final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvTicketCategory);


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
         @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            if (i == 0) {

                Category = listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent(TicketCategory.this, Subcategory.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        }

        });
}

  private void populateTicketCategoryList()
   {
        ArrayList<CompTicketCategory> arrayOfTicket = CompTicketCategory.getTicket();

    CompTicketCategoryAdapter adapter = new CompTicketCategoryAdapter(this, arrayOfTicket);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvTicketCategory);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


}
 }
```

the code for the second activity is:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Subcategory extends AppCompatActivity {

public String Category;
public static String Subcat;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_subcategory);


    populateSubcategoryList();

    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvSubcategory);
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Subcategory.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Subcat = listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Subcategory.this, SubmitTicket.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

and this is the code for the activity where both of the clicked items should be displayed:

```
public class SubmitTicket extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_submit_ticket);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_priority);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.priority_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    final Button butt = findViewById(R.id.submit);
    butt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {
        public void onClick (View view){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The ticket has been submitted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
   TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Category_submit_report);
   textView.setText(TicketCategory.Category);

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Subcategory_submit_report);
    tv.setText(Subcategory.Subcat);


}
```

Please help me. i would appreciate any output. thanks!

**UPDATE:**
after trying

```
 CompTicketCategory model = listView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                Category=model.Category; // your Category variable
                Category=model.getCategory();
```

this error is shown;

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6ZN0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try this in your `TicketCategory` actvity

**Use this:**

```
CompSubcategory  model = listView.getItemAtPosition(i);
Category=model.Category; // your Category variable
Category=model.getCategory(); // or use getter setter method
```

**Instead of this:**

```
Category = listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
```

Comment: toString is fine as well if you implement a custom toString method

Comment: @ZUNJAE yes you are right nut looking at the screenshot in question i don't thing OP has implemented `toString()` method

Comment: it gives a java.lang.ClassCastException

Comment: @user9799719 share that exception with question

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Intent Extra` Feature.

In the First Activity,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Subcategory.this, SubmitTicket.class);
switch1.putExtra("deviceID", listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString(););
startActivity(intent);
```

Then Next activity recall them,

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String data = intent.getStringExtra("data");
```

Comment: no it shows the path of the string but not the string itself.

Comment: address means current position of the list view isn't it?

Comment: In here it gives only the position. Do you load this data from a modal or pre defined array list?